# IPv6 on Amazon VPC: missing default route in Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipv6, amazon-vpc, dhcpv6

Now that [Amazon has extended IPv6](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-ipv6-update-global-support-spanning-15-regions-multiple-aws-services/) support for VPC to most of their global regions including eu-west-1, I'm trying to get my instances connected. Unfortunately I can't get routing to work.

I've followed the steps in the [migration guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html), i.e. I've associated an IPv6 CIDR to our VPC, assigned a part of that to our 'public' subnet, updated the VPC route table to send `::/0` through the igw (internet gateway), made sure that route table is assigned to the public subnet and assigned IPv6 addresses to some new Ubuntu 16.04 instances from the Console.

I then configured Ubuntu to get the assigned address via DHCPv6 [as described here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html#ipv6-dhcpv6-ubuntu), by adding `iface eth0 inet6 dhcp` to the networking setup and rebooting.

When I reboot the instance it takes a few minutes longer to start up but eventually I can log in and `ip a s` shows both a IPv4 and a global IPv6 address configured.

However, the v6 network isn't working:

```
# ping6 www.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

The route table is indeed missing a default route:

```
# ip -6 route
2001:DB8:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 9001
```

Manually adding a default v6 route, via `ip -6 route add default dev eth0` leads to a routing table that look correct:

```
# ip -6 route
2001:DB8:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234:1234 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 9001
default dev eth0  metric 1024
```

Unfortunately, this results in a different error:

```
# ping6 www.google.com
PING www.google.com(dh-in-x6a.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
From dh-in-x6a.1e100.net icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From dh-in-x6a.1e100.net icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From dh-in-x6a.1e100.net icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

*Isn't the DHCPv6-client supposed to take care of adding a default route? And why can I not reach the outside world even then?*

Comment: Migration guide: *"You can configure your Ubuntu instance to dynamically recognize any IPv6 address assigned to the network interface. If your instance does not have an IPv6 address, this configuration may cause the boot time of your instance to be extended by up to 5 minutes."*  You mentioned the increased boot time you observed. Is `2001:DB8:1234...` the address you assigned to the instance?  Perhaps the instance's console output (accessible from the EC2 console) will explain what's happening that causes that delay.

Comment: I first assigned an IPv6 address to the instance in the Console, which the DHCPv6 client succesfully picks up (despite the delay). I'll take a look at the system log during the boot process. Good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I missed a step in the migration guide.

When enabling IPv6 on an existing VPC some things, like route tables and security groups, have to be manually updated if you've made modifications to the default ones.

I had updated our route table (as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html#vpc-migrate-ipv6-routes) and security-groups (as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html#vpc-migrate-ipv6-sg-rules), but had forgotten to update our Network ACL, as mentioned on that same page.

So, I was effectively firewalling all IPv6 traffic. Adding inbound and outbound ALLOW rules for `::/0` fixed my problem for *Ubuntu 16.04*.

For *Ubuntu 14.04* there was actually an error in Amazon's migration guide, which has since been fixed. The advice to add `iface eth0 inet6 dhcp` to `/etc/networking/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg` didn't work, leading to a configured IPv6 address, but a missing default route.

Instead, I had to start the dhcp-client when the interface came up, like so: `up dhclient -6`. I ended up with the following working configuration in the `/etc/networking/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg` file:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    up dhclient -6 -v -pf /run/dhclient6.$IFACE.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.$IFACE.leases $IFACE
```

It appears Amazon has updated their migration guide to say something similar (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html#ipv6-dhcpv6-ubuntu-14).

Answer (score 3):

Your routing table does not look correct. This line looks very wrong:

```
default dev eth0  metric 1024
```

This line says that the entire internet is connected directly to your `eth0` interface without needing to go through any intermediate routers. This will cause your system to send neighor discovery requests onto the LAN for every host it tries to reach. And if that host is not directly connected to your LAN, it will not see the neighbor discovery request.

So you cannot really expect anything to work with that routing table. With some routers it is possible to configure a neighboring router to work around your misconfiguration. But you shouldn't count on it. Instead you should find out what the correct gateway address is and configure that.

Here is an example of what the routing table entry looks like on one particular machine with functional connectivity:

```
default via fe80::1 dev eth0  metric 1024  advmss 1220
```

The `via fe80::1` part is what is missing from yours. The address you are supposed to use may be different from `fe80::1`, you would need to ask your provider what gateway address to use if they haven't told you so. The two ways I have mostly seen providers choose to address their gateway is either `fe80::1` or the `/64` prefix followed by `::1` which in your case would become `2001:DB8:1234:1234::1`.

The `advmss 1220` part is not absolutely necessary, but I include it because it will work around some MTU issues.

Once you have fixed the routing table entry the next steps to test is to verify that the router shows up in your neighbor cache. And then use `traceroute6` or `mtr` to see how far you can get packets before they get lost.

Comment: Is that `advmss 1220` still needed? It's something I would have expected to see in 2010 when most places had broken deployments, not in 2017.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is rarely needed. But as long as there are people looking for excuses to not deploy IPv6 I want to give them as few excuses as possible. And if I can avoid a PMTU problem for a user by advertising a smaller MSS, that means one less excuse for somebody to not upgrade to IPv6.

Comment: You're right. I didn't fully understand it when I added that default route.  Thanks for explaining why. On AWS the gateway has a different address though. `default via fe80::481:12ff:fe99:7697 dev eth0` works for me. Now I still need to figure out why Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't autoconfigure the default route.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels That gateway address looks like it might change if the provider ever replace the router. It is possible they might have intended you to use `2001:DB8:1234:1234::1` as the gateway address. (But of course anything your provider have told you about the gateway address should be more accurate than what you read elsewhere on the internet.)

Comment: @kasperd It's the autoconfigured address provided by DHCPv6 on AWS, at least on Ubuntu 16.04. If it ever changes I'm guessing DHCPv6 will configure the new one. Which is why I want to get the autoconfiguration to work in 14.04 as well and avoid hardcoding it there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, despite the fact that the route table had a route for ::/0 that pointed to the igw for the VPC.  The problem was that the firewall ruleset was blocking ICMPv6 packets for the Neighbor Discovery Protocol.

You certainly need to permit icmp6types 133,134,135,136,137