# Connecting to Amazon AWS over SSH via IPv6

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ipv6, amazon-vpc

For the past couple weeks I tried configuring an AWS Instance to be reachable via IPv6. However I can't seem to connect to this Machine (Ubuntu Server 16) using an SSH Connection.

Heres what I did so far:

- I created a public VPC with an IPv4 and IPv6 CIDR Block.
- Therein lies a subnet with autoassigned IPv4 and 6 Adresses
- I created an Internet-Gateway (IGW) and had the routing Tables point all outgoing traffic to it:
  [Routing Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyW7a.png)
- I set up the ACL to allow ALL incoming SSH Traffic: [ACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sioyV.png)

Now, while I can access the machine unsing it's public IPv4 Adress and DNS-Name, I can't establish a connection via IPv6

Am I missing a step in configuration or is IPv6 not fully supported in my AWS Region yet? (eu-central-1)

UPDATE:

The Instance does have an IPv6 Adress and it's security group allows inbound SSH Connections:

iDOTstackDOTimgurDOTcomSLASHMkNhcDOTpng
iDOTstackDOTimgurDOTcomSLASHFRcY4DOTpng

Yet whenever I try to connect to it via its IPv6 adress, I get a "Network is unreachable" Error

Comment: What about security group rules?

Comment: Does the EC2 console show your instance having an IPv6 address? Have you added appropriate security group and NACL rules? Your screen shots are difficult to understand without context, don't crop so hard, show what the entries are associated with - eg NACL in tab, SG out tab.

Comment: Also what is the error when doing `ssh` with verbose level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colleague of mine figured it out eventually.

Turns out all I had to do was to manually invoke

`sudo dhclient -6`

to force a dhcp lookup over IPv6.

Since the interface already showed an ipv6 address I assumed that DHCP was working.

Regardless, I am glad we got it working and I hope this information can help other people avoid this issue.

Regards
Ollowain

Comment: Seems related to a bugs that also appear in ubuntu 14.04
https://serverfault.com/questions/829032/ipv6-on-amazon-vpc-missing-default-route-in-ubuntu